# Force reinterpret_cast to return nullptr

Tags: c++, unit-testing, casting, reinterpret-cast

I'm creating unit test for a function that receives a memory address as an `unsigned long`

Inside the function, this addres is `reinterpret_cast`ed into a pointer of one of ur  classes.

```
void my function(Address inputAdress ) // Address comes from: typedef unsigned long Address;
{
  ClsMyClassThread* ptr = reinterpret_cast<ClsMyClassThread*>(inputAdress);

  if(ptr == nullptr)
  {
    // Do something 
  }
}
```

This function works well, but when creating the UnitTest for it, I can't figure out how can I force `ptr` to be `nullptr` (I want to test full coverage). When can this happen? Is that even posible?

Thanks!

Comment: An integer value of 0 is normally casted to a `nullptr`.

Comment: Cast `nullptr` to the parameter type, pass it to the function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [`reinterpret_cast` conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) point 3 (emphasis mine):

> 3. A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type. **A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size and back to the same pointer type is guaranteed to have its original value**, otherwise the resulting pointer cannot be dereferenced safely (the round-trip conversion in the opposite direction is not guaranteed; the same pointer may have multiple integer representations) **The null pointer constant `NULL` or integer zero is not guaranteed to yield the null pointer value of the target type**; `static_cast` or implicit conversion should be used for this purpose.

So the pedantically correct way to do this (assuming `sizeof(Address)` is large enough) is:

```
myfunction(reinterpret_cast<Address>(static_cast<ClsMyClassThread*>(nullptr)));
```

whereas the following what some people suggest is **not** guaranteed to work:

```
myfunction(0);
```

Comment: @dyp Sorry now it's my turn to be confused because I don't understand what you're claiming.

Comment: So if you do `reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(nullptr))`, what's the result? It's the same as `reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>((void*)0))`.

Comment: Basically, it's integral -> pointer -> integral. And if that's guaranteed to retain value, then the `uintptr_t` has value `0`...

Comment: @dyp Even though it seems logical, `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>((void*) 0) == 0` is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @dyp I think it's ill-formed. I don't see [expr.reinterpret.cast] allowing a conversion from `std::nullptr_t` to integral type. It doesn't even allow `std::nullptr_t` to pointer type.

Comment: @aschepler The conversion is allowed in https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4

Comment: @dyp Note that _"the conversion has the same meaning and validity as a conversion of `(void*)0` to the integral type."_ does **not** claim that the conversion will result into `0`. Think of `(void*) 0` as some 'magic nullpointer object' that might have any unspecified bit pattern, because that's how the standard views it.

Comment: I think what breaks it is the requirement "A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size [...] and back to the *same pointer type*". `void* != ClsMyClassThread*`

Comment: @dyp Oops, yes, missed that.

Comment: I think that requirement is too strict. It doesn't even allow `T t; (T const*)(uintptr_t)&t`...

Comment: Is `myfunction(0);` an *implementation defined behavior* or an *undefined behavior*?  The "not guaranteed" seems wishy-washy, and to me suggests implementation defined behavior, which may be good enough for the OP.

Comment: @Eljay Implementation-defined. [\[expr.reinterpret.cast\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.reinterpret.cast#5)

Comment: See also: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#463

Answer (score 6):

Most likely these will work:

```
my_function(NULL);
my_function(0);
Address a = 0;
my_function(a);
```

Though to be absolutely technically correct, you would need:

```
my_function(reinterpret_cast<Address>(static_cast<ClsMyClassThread*>(nullptr)));
```

(The Standard guarantees conversion from a zero to pointer type is a null pointer value only when the zero involved is a direct literal expression, not a variable such as `inputAdress` which happens to have value zero. So instead this uses the guarantee on two inverse `reinterpret_cast` expressions.)